# Altering the website using Chrome Inspector

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

Let's say I have a form that contains an hidden field that holds the ID of an editing record. Using the chrome developer tools, someone decides to modify the hidden element of the form, to something else. The person then submits the form.

My question: What is the value that hidden field when it is sent to the server? Is it the original value or the modified value?

---

Another example - Similar

There is a form that contains 3 input fields (name = txt1,txt2,txt3). Can someone use the chrome inspector to change the name attribute of input fields and make a request?

Comment: If someone changes the value of a hidden form field and submits it, the server will receive the changed value.The name attribute of a field can be changed in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your question

> What is the value that hidden field when it is sent to the server? Is it the original value or the modified value?

Your server will receive the modified value. Hence the importance of both client-side and server-side validation.

The usual practice for proper validation on the server side is **never trust** the values from client side. Keep that perspective in mind and you will have better validation.

> There is a form that contains 3 input fields (name = txt1,txt2,txt3). Can someone use the chrome inspector to change the name attribute of input fields and make a request?

Yes the input name will also change. Thus your server should know that the expected input based on the name) is never received and throw back error message.

Comment: What are some techniques used to validate the client-side information?

Comment: Validation on the client side is usually to make sure the user entered the correct format, and there are many plugins to do that ( [parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) looks promising). If you are concerned about the modification, pay more attention to server-side validation.